# Finding minimum sum of non consecutive elements

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, memoization

I'm trying to find the minimum sum of non consecutive elements in list,
where every time I can jump one cell or two cells.
The first cell is not counted in sum.

The **implementation has to include recursion and memoization**. I tried to implement such method, but unfortunately, it doesn't actually use memoization and it doesn't work for some examples.

My code looks like this:

```
def optimal_cruise_seasick(toilet_prices):
    prices_dict = {}
    return optimal_cruise_seasick_mem(toilet_prices, 0, len(toilet_prices), prices_dict)

def optimal_cruise_seasick_mem(prices_lst, start, end, dic):
    if (start,end) in dic:
        return dic[(start,end)]
    if(start + 1 == end or start + 2 == end):
        return prices_lst[end-1]
    min_cost = prices_lst[end-1]
    i = start + 1
    while(i < end - 1):
        one = optimal_cruise_seasick_mem(prices_lst, i, i+1, dic)
        two = optimal_cruise_seasick_mem(prices_lst, i, i+2, dic)
        if (one <= two):
            min_cost += one
            i += 1
        else:
            min_cost += two
            i += 2
        dic[(start,end)] = min_cost
    return min_cost
```

I tried to run it for `toilet_prices = [20,40,60,80,100,70,50,30,10,30]`.

It returns 320 instead of 250 (40,80,70,30,30). How should I fix my code so it will work as required?

Thanks!

Comment: You have underspecified your problem. Is 40, 100, 30 a legal sequence? (Start at 40, skip 2, 100, skip 2, 30, skip 2, end of list.) And if you do not count the 20 in your sum at all, why are you not just cutting off the first element of the prices list to begin with?

Comment: @Galc127,can you add a few more expected outputs

Comment: Oh, now that I look at your code, I see that when you say "non consecutive" in the title, you don't actually mean non-consecutive, since you can, in fact have consecutive elements in the list being counted towards the sum.

Comment: @senshin, it is not skipping, but going to, hence moving to cells from 40 is going to 80. A legal sequence for example might be (start at 40, move 2, 80, move 1, 100, move 2, 50, move 2, 10, move 1, 30, end).

Comment: Okay, what about 40, 80, 70, 30, 10 - which yields 230? Is that legal? (Start at 40, move 2, 80, move 2, 70, move 2, 30, move 1, 10, move 2, end of list)

Comment: @senshin, we always have to move to the last cell and it is counted in sum, hence if we get to the 10 we only can move 1. We can't get out of list.

Comment: What should be the answer for `[3, 2 ,7 ,10]`?

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation is, frankly, confusing. I have written an alternate implementation that works correctly (per your clarifications in the comments), though I don't know if it's memoizing in the way you want it to.

What we do is start at the first "actual" thing in the prices list (stripping off the first element; in your example, 20), and then successively see whether chopping off the left one or left two elements gives us a lower sum.

```
def f(prices, memo):
    if prices not in memo:
        if len(prices) == 1:
            memo[prices] = prices[0]
        elif len(prices) == 2:
            # We must include the final cell in the list, but can choose to get there
            # either by two 1-moves or one 2-move. Obviously the one 2-move is going
            # to be non-pessimal if all prices are non-negative, but we'll put the min
            # call in here for elucidation/explicitness anyway.
            memo[prices] = min(prices[1], prices[0] + prices[1])
        else:
            memo[prices] = prices[0] + min(f(prices[1:], memo), f(prices[2:], memo))
    return memo[prices]

def optimal_cruise_seasick(prices):
    return f(prices[1:], dict())
```

Adding some print statements to indicate when we read from memo:

```
>>> optimal_cruise_seasick((20,40,60,80,100,70,50,30,10,30))
Read from memo: (10, 30) -> 30
Read from memo: (30, 10, 30) -> 60
Read from memo: (50, 30, 10, 30) -> 80
Read from memo: (70, 50, 30, 10, 30) -> 130
Read from memo: (100, 70, 50, 30, 10, 30) -> 180
Read from memo: (80, 100, 70, 50, 30, 10, 30) -> 210
250
```

As you can see, it's memoizing over suffixes of the prices list.

---

I should add that you can achieve the same effect in a cleaner way using [`functools.lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache). The `f2` here is equivalent to the `f` above (if your price lists are short enough that everything fits into the cache), except that you don't pass in a `dict()` for `memo`, obviously.

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def f2(prices):
    if len(prices) == 1:
        return prices[0]
    elif len(prices) == 2:
        return min(prices[1], prices[0] + prices[1])
    else:
        return prices[0] + min(f2(prices[1:]), f2(prices[2:]))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the code doesn't work. For [50,30,10,30] it returns 60 instead of 40 (10,30).

Comment: @Galc127, `10,30` are consecutive so how could that be the answer?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, 50 is not counted, hence we move 2 steps, paying 10, then moving one step, paying 30. In total we paid 40.

Comment: @Galc127, so the last elements can be consecutive?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, You can go one step or two steps any time. If the least payment is gotten by going only one step each time, then the result shall be all of the list except for the first element.

Comment: @Galc127, then you are not summing non consecutive elements, you should add a few more examples of input with expected output

Comment: @Galc127 Okay, do you see where the issue is? It should be pretty clear. I interpreted your procedure for [50, 30, 10, 30] as "skip 50 altogether, start at 30, move 2, 30, end" for a total of 60. But you seem to want "start at 50, move 2, 10, move 1, 30, end, but then subtract the initial 50" for a total of 40. It is trivial to change the code I posted so that it returns the answer you want. I leave it as an exercise to you to do so. Again, this is why it is important to clearly specify your problem in full detail when you ask your question.